# Exporting worksheets to workbooks with exceptions

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to export all worksheets into seperate workbooks. I am almost done with everything but I would like to export only worksheets where the value in cell H32 is higher than 0. I also want to exclude worksheets named "macro" and "report". I put `If Sheets(N).Name <> "macro" And Sheets(N).Name <> "report" Then Sheets(N).Select Replace:=False` after `For N = 1 To Sheets.Count` but it didn't work.

```
Sub exporttoworkbook()
Dim Sheet As Worksheet, SheetName$, MyFilePath$, N&
MyFilePath$ = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Statements of Work"
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
     '      End With
    On Error Resume Next '<< a folder exists
    MkDir MyFilePath '<< create a folder
    For N = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Sheets(N).Activate
        SheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4").Value
        Cells.Copy
        Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            With .ActiveSheet
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                .Name = "Quality Sign-off"
                [A1].Select
            End With
             'save book in this folder
            .SaveAs FileName:=MyFilePath _
            & "\" & SheetName & ".xlsx"
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
        .CutCopyMode = False
    Next
End With
End Sub
```

I am also struggling with PasteSpecial in my macro. I want to paste values and formatting but NOT formulas. I am onlu able to paste numbers without formating. Could you also please help me with this?

Regards,
Adrian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (I modified your loop):

```
For N = 1 To Sheets.Count
    If LCase(Sheets(N).Name) <> "macro" And LCase(Sheets(N).Name) <> "report" And Sheets(N).Range("H32").Value > 0 Then
        Sheets(N).Activate
        SheetName = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$4").Value
        Cells.Copy
        Workbooks.Add (xlWBATWorksheet)
        With ActiveWorkbook
            With .ActiveSheet
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .PasteSpecial Paste:=8
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                .Name = "Quality Sign-off"
                [A1].Select
            End With
            'save book in this folder
            .SaveAs FileName:=MyFilePath _
            & "\" & SheetName & ".xlsx"
            .Close SaveChanges:=True
        End With
        .CutCopyMode = False
    End If
Next
```

Maybe the reason it doesn't work was cause by different capitalisation, so I added lowering all leters in sheet name :)

Comment: thank you for the code. I used lower-cased letters and it worked however I am still strugling to export only worksheets where the value in cell H32 is higher than 0 and with pastespecial function. Do you know how can I solve these issues?

Comment: @Adrian Included condition with the H32 cell. About `PaseSpecial` - please be more specific, or even ask another question :)

Comment: each worksheet has the same table in the same cells but the values are different. The total sum of this table is in cell H32 in each worksjeet. What I would like to do is to export worksheet only if the value in cell H32 is higher than 0. When it comes to PasteSpecial, I put  `.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats` in my code but macro doesn't copy format of my worksheet, only numbers and I am not sure what else can I do to fix that.